# Is the Unit of Work pattern really needed with Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, design-patterns

My question is about Entity Framework and the Unit of Work pattern. Is the Unit of Work pattern really needed with Entity Framework ? I mean it look like i see this pattern quiet a lots of time, however isn't the feature of "Transaction" already applied in EF4 ?

Thanks,

Comment: Old question, but a more extensive answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940854/is-unit-of-work-and-repository-patterns-very-useful-for-big-projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it really needed? no, it isn't...

Having said that, I use it as a layer of abstraction for my tests, and found it very useful